# Why I can't access JSON dictionary element using dot notation?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a following JSON representation:

```
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(
 {
   1 : {
        2: "2"
   }  
}
));
```

Why cant I  access key "2" using dot notation (i.e. `collectionCopy.1.2`) ?

Comment: That's just an object now you've parsed it. Use `collectionCopy['1']['2']`

Comment: you need to use collectionCopy['1']['2'] its doesnt know you mean strings not actual numbers

Comment: To access as collectionCopy.1, property 1 is not a valid JavaScript identifier. You can only properties that are valid JavaScript identifiers with dot notation.

Comment: You know that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(` does nothing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the keys are strings not actual numbers:

to access it use:

```
collectionCopy[1][2]
```

or

```
collectionCopy['1']['2']
```

[Relevant docs on accessing properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: but when i have a regular object `var newObject = {1:{2:"2"}};`, i can use dot notation `newObject.1.2`. Is this because i have `.stringify()`? Or JSON turns every key and value of key to string anyway?

Thank you for docs, ill read them.

Comment: can you show me where that works? I just tried it and I cannot get it to work:
https://jsbin.com/tevebi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I assumed that it should work :D I think i just messed with simple syntax. `newObject.1.2` doesn't work and it shouldn't. But if I had object like this one `var newObject = {one:{two:"2"}}` `console.log(newObject.one.two)` prints `"2"` to console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dot notation for accessing an object's properties only on a valid identifiers in the language.

And since numbers (or anything that starts with a number) are not a valid identifiers you can access it (as a property of an object) only with the bracket notation.